# JFrame & JWindow Conflicts

Tags: java, swing, jframe, splash-screen, jwindow

I have a faulty code and I know where the problem lies, but I don't know how to implement the solution. I want to make a program, which on click of a button opens a PDF in a intern PDF Reader. This works great so far but since it loads a few seconds I wanted to implement a splash screen showing a logo using JWindow. But since my PDF Reader also uses GUI, they seem to conflict since the JWindow doesn't appear. I know that the official SplashScreen class is recommended as a better solution but I can't find a simple tutorial on how to use this so I went with the JWindow Version. Can someone help me implement a solution to this code?

Help would be much appreciated

**Loading Screen Class**

```
package pdf;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class loadingScreen extends JWindow {
BorderLayout bl = new BorderLayout();
JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();
JPanel barPanel = new JPanel();
FlowLayout barPanelLayout = new FlowLayout();
JProgressBar progress = new JProgressBar();
ImageIcon icon;
public loadingScreen(ImageIcon icon) {

this.icon = icon;
try {
  lsInit();
}

catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}



}

public void lsInit() throws Exception{

this.imageLabel.setIcon(this.icon);
this.getContentPane().setLayout(bl);
barPanel.setLayout(this.barPanelLayout);
barPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
this.getContentPane().add(this.imageLabel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
//this.getContentPane().add(this.barPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
//barPanel.add(this.progress,null);
this.setSize(new Dimension(500,500));
this.setVisible(true);
this.pack();

}



public void setScreenVisible(boolean b) {
setVisible(b);
 }

}
```

**PDF Reader with Usage of Loading Screen**

```
      package pdf;

  import java.awt.SplashScreen;
  import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
  import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
  import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
  import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
  import java.io.File;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.util.List;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfviewer.PDFPagePanel;
  import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
  import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;

  public class PDFViewer {
    int currentPageNo = 0;
    loadingScreen screen;

    public PDFViewer(String path) {

      File pdf_path = new File(path);
      try {
        splashScreenInit();
       PDDocument inputPdf = PDDocument.load(pdf_path);
        List<PDPage> allPgs = inputPdf.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
        PDPage testPage = (PDPage)allPgs.get(0);

        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        testFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
          public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            try {
              inputPdf.close();
              testFrame.setVisible(false);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e1.printStackTrace();
            }

          }
        });
        PDFPagePanel pdfPanel = new PDFPagePanel();
        pdfPanel.setPage(testPage);
        testFrame.add(pdfPanel);
        testFrame.setBounds(0, 0, pdfPanel.getWidth(), pdfPanel.getHeight()+50);
        testFrame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

          @Override
          public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }

          @Override
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN ) {
              if(currentPageNo < allPgs.size()-1) {
                currentPageNo++;
                PDPage currentPage = (PDPage)allPgs.get(currentPageNo);
                pdfPanel.setPage(currentPage);
                testFrame.add(pdfPanel);
                testFrame.invalidate();
                testFrame.validate();
                testFrame.repaint();

              }
            }

            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
              if(currentPageNo>0) {
                currentPageNo--;
                PDPage currentPage = (PDPage)allPgs.get(currentPageNo);
                pdfPanel.setPage(currentPage);
                testFrame.add(pdfPanel);
                testFrame.invalidate();
                testFrame.validate();
                testFrame.repaint();
              }
            }

          }

          @Override
          public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          }

        });
        splashScreenDestruct();
        testFrame.setVisible(true);

      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    public void splashScreenInit() {
      ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("resources/BASF_logo_logotype.png");//Splashscrreen
      screen = new loadingScreen(logo);
      //screen.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      //screen.setScreenVisible(true);
      //screen.setProgressMax(100);


    }

    public void splashScreenDestruct() {
      screen.setScreenVisible(false);
      screen = null;
    }

  }
```

Comment: `I know that the official SplashScreen class is recommended as a better solution but I can't find a simple tutorial on how to use this ` - See:  [How to Create a Splash Screen](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)

Comment: Yeah I was on this site. But how would I insert the splash screen in my PDF Reader program so that it is showing a picture when loading? As far as I understand the splash screen gets shown when the program starts up? Thank you in advance

Comment: `public class loadingScreen extends JWindow {` That's the first mistake that the `SplashScreen` avoids. It uses the AWT based `Window` to allow the screen to appear before the Swing API is loaded.

Comment: @camickr I checked out the demo and managed to implement the splash screen but my problem is that the image is shown on start of the program and not while the content is loading. When I try to add the splash screen code to the working code, I get the error "No SplashScreen available". How to insert the image so that the program can work in the background ?